# Python - Ignoring string from a list is not working

Tags: python

Below code is written to select directories based on an Ignore list:

```
mypath = 'c:\\Windows\\help'
ignorelist = ['mui', 'en-US']
for root, directories, filenames in walk(mypath):
    for directory in directories :
        if not any(ignorestring in directory for ignorestring in ignorelist):
            print(join(root,directory))
```

When the ignorelist variable list is empty, below is the output:

```
c:\Windows\help\Corporate
c:\Windows\help\Help
c:\Windows\help\mui
c:\Windows\help\OEM
c:\Windows\help\Windows
c:\Windows\help\Help\en-US
c:\Windows\help\mui\0409
c:\Windows\help\Windows\en-US
```

with ['mui', 'en-US'] in ignore list the output is:

```
c:\Windows\help\Corporate
c:\Windows\help\Help
c:\Windows\help\OEM
c:\Windows\help\Windows
c:\Windows\help\mui\0409
```

"c:\Windows\help\mui\0409" not ignored even though mui is in the ignore list.

Please clarify why this is happening and how to ignore all subdirectories of mui folder

Comment: what is the output when you put 'help' in your ignoreList variable?

Comment: could it be that `directory` only refers to what's after the last slash ?
so in `c:\Windows\help\mui\0409`, `directory` is actually `'0409'`.. check that

Comment: @OmarEinea It is like that

Comment: @AjayGupta Yeap, so that's the problem just as described in the answer below

Comment: use path as well @OmarEinea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply your criteria on `path` rather than just `directory`:

```
from os.path import join
from os import walk

mypath = 'c:\\Windows\\help'
ignorelist = ['mui', 'en-US']

for root, directories, filenames in walk(mypath):
    for directory in directories:
        path = join(root, directory)
        if not any(ignorestring in path for ignorestring in ignorelist):
            print(path)

c:\Windows\help\Corporate
c:\Windows\help\Help
c:\Windows\help\OEM
c:\Windows\help\Windows
```